# I am trying to use scapy on python3 on my macosX; however, I get the following error: OSError: Cannot find libdnet.so

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, pcap

I am trying to use scapy to read a pcap file on my MacOSx using Python 3.
However, when I run the following code:

from scapy.all import rdpcap

I get the following error:

OSError: Cannot find libdnet.so

I looked up how to install libdnet, but I was not able to find out how to install for Python 3. How do you either fix this error or download this package?

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade to Scapy's current development version from [the official repository](https://github.com/secdev/scapy).